How do I change a div.description with CSS code?
I am trying to change some HTML code but the HTML is not editable so my developer made a CSS box so I can edit items. There  is this one area where we want to change the word "holders" to "patient" and "KiSSes to KiSS" but I dont know how to write that in CSS code.
 
"View and manage all KiSSes Holders"
I have googled for help but nothing really comes up

You can't change html content with CSS.

You cannot do those things with css, you need javascript. We can still help you with that but you have to post the html code. Update your question and I am sure we will find a solution for you.

Please use javascript code for that.
You can use innerHTML attribute to update/change the inner text of the element.

I used javascript but now I cannot click on the button anymore, it disappeared. I spoke to my coder & he said it breaks the HTML - what does that mean?

I may need to check the code, but I think it breaks the html code when you get the element incorrectly. I guess you got the element by using getElementById?
